# Cannot read property 'match' of undefined while making a form field alphanumeic

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, alphanumeric

The 'Reference Number' field in my form is supposed to be alphanumeric. If user enters anything invalid, I want to display the error. But I am getting the error - **Cannot read property 'match' of undefined**. Below is my javascript code:

```
else if(Boolean(contractReferenceNumber)){
        console.log("reference number is:" + contractReferenceNumber);
        alphanumeric(contractReferenceNumber);
        function alphanumeric(text) {
            var letters = /^([0-9]|[a-z])+([0-9a-z]+)$/i;

            if(text.value.match(letters)) {
                console.log("the reference number is alphanumeric");
            }
            else{
                swal({
                    type: 'error',
                    title: 'Error',
                    text: 'Please enter valid reference number',
                  })
            }
        }
    }
```

The java related part is:

```
else if(contractReferenceNumber != null) {
        String alphanumeric = "^([0-9]|[a-z])+([0-9a-z]+)$";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(alphanumeric);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(contractReferenceNumber);

        if(matcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println("The reference number is alphanumeric");
        }
        else {
            log.warn("Please enter valid reference number");
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(ciCustContractHdrDto);
        }           
    }
```

Can anybody please help me..

Comment: The error means that `text.value` is undefined..

Comment: You posted nothing that could explain what the value of `contractReferenceNumber` is.

Comment: contractReferenceNumber takes the value from the input field.
var contractReferenceNumber = $('#referenceNumber').val();

Comment: i tried removing "value" from text.value.match() and it worked! Thankyou guys :)